# How do I create a new python virtual environment with certain python version?

Tags: python, virtual-environment

I have seen many solutions for this but I didn't get a satisfying answer for this. I have created a python virtual environment [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)
as following

```
pip3 install virtualenv //first installed virtualenv 
python3 -m venv name_of_virtual_env
```

I have the `python version 3.5.2` in my system which is the latest one in my system. I learned that by default the python version in the virtual environment will be the latest one in the base environment. I wanted `python version 3.6.0`or above in the new virtual environment.

(1) If it is possible to upgrade the python version from `python 3.5.2` to `python 3.6.0` or above?
(2) Is there any other possibility to create a new virtual environment without changing the python version in the base environment something like the following in the anaconda environment.

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6 
//This lines will create an environment named py36
```

Most of the site gives the following solution but this also takes the default python version which is `3.5.2`.

```
virtualenv -p python3 new_p3_env
```

I have almost done good research about this but could not find the solution. Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Comment: this is what pyenv is made for -> https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv